# Is there any application/tool for quick translations of a selected word?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a simple application or tool that enables me to quickly translate a selected word (for example when reading a pdf or document).

I know there are several applications that offer translations but I'm rather looking for just a small tool that completely runs in the background and uses the notification system for a quick translation of a selected word when a certain hotkey is pressed.

Especially German - English, English - German would be great.

Thank you very much for your help!

Lots of greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [**Stardict**](http://www.stardict.org/)

[image]

You may find German dictionary from the main site. Or from this http://cihar.com/software/slovnik/

To install stardict, you may install from software center or running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install stardict
```

After you install stardict and dictionary click on the setting icon on the bottom and define selection key like the screenshot shows:

[image]

Selection translation looks like this on pdf:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this descriptive and helpful response.
It is just what I've been looking for.
(As soon as I'm able to upvote I will) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the hotkey function in Stardict works quite unreliably in Ubuntu 14.04

An alternative is GoldenDict. To install goldendict in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install goldendict
```

Select word -> Ctrl + C + C

 (it should be enabled by default, otherwise check "Preferences")